# Rational of the form $n^{n^q}$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q},n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$, without representation as $n^p$, where $p\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: number-theory

Is there a rational of the form $n^{n^q}$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0,1\}$, that cannot be written in the form $n^p$, where $p\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.  $n^q$ is algebraic.  By Gelfond-Schneider, if it is not rational $n^{n^q}$ is transcendental.

Comment: In order to have concrete examples in which the thing being proven is not vacuous, let me just add that it is a very fun exercise to show that the natural logarithms of the primes are linearly independent over the rationals (and hence over the algebraics by Gelfond-Schneider). One therefore has that $\log_p(q) = \frac{\log(q)}{\log(p)}$ is transcendental whenever $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.